# Update specific values in a dataframe based on array index position

Tags: r

Let's say I have a dataframe

```
> colA <- c(1, 14, 8)
> colB <- c(4, 8, 9)
> colC <- c(1, 2, 14)
> df <- data.frame(c(colA, colB, colC))

> df
  colA colB colC
1    1    4    1
2   14    8    2
3    8    9   14
```

What I want to do is create a second data frame which has the same structure as df, but has 1 whenever a specific number is found, and 0 otherwise, e.g., if the number were 14, df2 would look like this

```
> df2 
  colA  colB  colC
1 0     0     0
2 1     0     0
3 0     0     1
```

I thought I could create a 3x3 data frame of 0s (df2), use `which()` to get the index for the number in df, and then use that index to change what shows up in  df2

```
> number <- 14
> index <- which(df == number)
> index
[1] 2 9
```

or perhaps more helpfully

```
> index <- which(df == number, arr.ind = T)
> index
     row col
[1,]   2   1
[2,]   3   3
```

However I am unsure how to use this index to specifiy which values in the df of NAs should be TRUE and which FALSE (i.e. how to reverse the which)?

NB - I will actually be testing this for multiple numbers, so I figured I would do it inside a for loop. So I want the final DF to show ones for every location which has any of the numbers (i.e. gradually switching the 0's "on" to 1's

```
> numbers <- c(14, 9, 1
> for(i in numbers){
>    index <- which(df == numbers, arr.ind = T)
>    #then do whatever needs to be done to change the index locations in df2
```

P.S., in general, I work in the tidyverse, so tidyverse specific solutions would be grand, but base r would also be brilliant.

Ohh, and yes, this is for day 4 of [Advent of Code](https://adventofcode.com/2021/day/4) - it's a useful challenge to help this non-expert coder learn.

Thanks

Comment: You can do `+(df == number)` i..e convert the `df` to a logical matrix and then reconvert to binary with `+` as `TRUE ->1` and `FALSE -> 0`

Comment: Side note, to get a correct data frame you should remove the `c()` around the arguments in the first code frame line 4.

Comment: Thanks Andre, yes I realised that after the fact, but clearly failed to update the repro. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a full example how it could be done.

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(colA = c(1, 14, 8), colB = c(4, 8, 9), colC = c(1, 
2, 14)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

**base R**

```
data.frame( sapply( df, function(x) as.numeric( x == 14 | x == 8 ) ))
  colA colB colC
1    0    0    0
2    1    1    0
3    1    0    1
```

for any number in a loop

```
setNames( data.frame( matrix( rowSums( sapply( c(14,8,1), function(x) 
  df==x ) ), dim(df) ) ), colnames( df ) )
  colA colB colC
1    1    0    1
2    1    1    0
3    1    0    1
```

**dplyr**

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% summarise_all( ~ as.numeric( .x == 14 | .x == 8 ) )
  colA colB colC
1    0    0    0
2    1    1    0
3    1    0    1

# or
df %>% summarise( across( everything(), ~ as.numeric( .x == 14 | .x == 8 ) ) )
  colA colB colC
1    0    0    0
2    1    1    0
3    1    0    1
```